# Build hadoop-common 3.3.0 on ubuntu 22.04 with error

Tags: hadoop

## Enviroments

Followed by `BUILDING.txt`

### Unix System

```
$ uname  
Linux
```

### JDK 1.8

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME  
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
```

### Maven 3.3 or later

```
$ mvn -v  
Apache Maven 3.6.3  
Maven home: /usr/share/maven  
Java version: 1.8.0_382, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre  
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8  
OS name: "linux", version: "6.2.0-32-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

### Protocol Buffers 3.7.1 (if compiling native code)

```
$ protoc --version  
libprotoc 3.20.3
```

### CMake 3.1 or newer (if compiling native code)

```
$ cmake --version  
cmake version 3.22.1  
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

### Zlib devel (if compiling native code)

```
$ python -c 'import zlib;print(zlib.ZLIB_VERSION)'  
1.2.13
```

### Cyrus SASL devel (if compiling native code)

```
$ saslpasswd2 -v  
This product includes software developed by Computing Services  
at Carnegie Mellon University (http://www.cmu.edu/computing/).  
Built against SASL API version 2.1.27  
LibSasl version 2.1.27 by "Cyrus SASL"
```

### One of the compilers that support thread_local storage: GCC 4.8.1 or later, Visual Studio, Clang (community version), Clang (version for iOS 9 and later) (if compiling native code)

```
$ gcc --version  
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0  
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.  
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO  
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

### openssl devel (if compiling native hadoop-pipes and to get the best HDFS encryption performance)

```
$ openssl version   
OpenSSL 1.1.1u  30 May 2023
```

## Run and execptions

After run `mvn clean install -DskipTests -Pdist,native` then follow exception:

```
[WARNING] make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native'
[WARNING] [ 38%] Linking C executable test_bulk_crc32
[WARNING] /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test_bulk_crc32.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
[WARNING] /usr/bin/cc -std=gnu99  -g -O2 -Wall -pthread -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -rdynamic CMakeFiles/test_bulk_crc32.dir/main/native/src/org/apache/hadoop/util/bulk_crc32.c.o CMakeFiles/test_bulk_crc32.dir/main/native/src/org/apache/hadoop/util/bulk_crc32_x86.c.o CMakeFiles/test_bulk_crc32.dir/main/native/src/test/org/apache/hadoop/util/test_bulk_crc32.c.o -o test_bulk_crc32 
[WARNING] make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native'
[WARNING] [ 38%] Built target test_bulk_crc32
[WARNING] make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native'
[WARNING] make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native'
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/exception.c: In function ‘terror’:
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/exception.c:118:34: error: ‘sys_nerr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
[WARNING]   118 |   if ((errnum < 0) || (errnum >= sys_nerr)) {
[WARNING]       |                                  ^~~~~~~~
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/exception.c:118:34: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/exception.c:121:10: error: ‘sys_errlist’ undeclared (first use in this function)
[WARNING]   121 |   return sys_errlist[errnum];
[WARNING]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/exception.c:123:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
[WARNING]   123 | }
[WARNING]       | ^
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/exception.c: In function ‘terror’:
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/exception.c:118:34: error: ‘sys_nerr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
[WARNING]   118 |   if ((errnum < 0) || (errnum >= sys_nerr)) {
[WARNING]       |                                  ^~~~~~~~
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/exception.c:118:34: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
[WARNING] make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hadoop.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/hadoop.dir/main/native/src/exception.c.o] Error 1
[WARNING] make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/exception.c:121:10: error: ‘sys_errlist’ undeclared (first use in this function)
[WARNING]   121 |   return sys_errlist[errnum];
[WARNING]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/exception.c:123:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
[WARNING]   123 | }
[WARNING]       | ^
[WARNING] make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hadoop_static.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/hadoop_static.dir/main/native/src/exception.c.o] Error 1
[WARNING] make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[WARNING] make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:113: CMakeFiles/hadoop_static.dir/all] Error 2
[WARNING] make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/org/apache/hadoop/crypto/random/OpensslSecureRandom.c: In function ‘locks_setup’:
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/org/apache/hadoop/crypto/random/OpensslSecureRandom.c:250:33: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dlsym_CRYPTO_num_locks’; did you mean ‘dlsym_CRYPTO_malloc’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
[WARNING]   250 |   lock_cs = dlsym_CRYPTO_malloc(dlsym_CRYPTO_num_locks() *  \
[WARNING]       |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[WARNING]       |                                 dlsym_CRYPTO_malloc
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/org/apache/hadoop/crypto/random/OpensslSecureRandom.c:257:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dlsym_CRYPTO_set_id_callback’; did you mean ‘CRYPTO_set_id_callback’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
[WARNING]   257 |   dlsym_CRYPTO_set_id_callback((unsigned long (*)())pthreads_thread_id);
[WARNING]       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[WARNING]       |   CRYPTO_set_id_callback
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/org/apache/hadoop/crypto/random/OpensslSecureRandom.c:258:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dlsym_CRYPTO_set_locking_callback’; did you mean ‘CRYPTO_set_locking_callback’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
[WARNING]   258 |   dlsym_CRYPTO_set_locking_callback((void (*)())pthreads_locking_callback);
[WARNING]       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[WARNING]       |   CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
[WARNING] At top level:
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/org/apache/hadoop/crypto/random/OpensslSecureRandom.c:261:13: warning: ‘locks_cleanup’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
[WARNING]   261 | static void locks_cleanup(void)
[WARNING]       |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[WARNING] /home/x/workspace/dp/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/org/apache/hadoop/crypto/random/OpensslSecureRandom.c:247:13: warning: ‘locks_setup’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
[WARNING]   247 | static void locks_setup(void)
[WARNING]       |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
[WARNING] make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:87: CMakeFiles/hadoop.dir/all] Error 2
[WARNING] make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

## Some try

Notice `sys_errlist` marked as deprecated,so down-grade gcc to 4.8.5,but with same errors.
Is here any dependencies I missed?

Comment: Why not use Java 11 or latest patch release 3.3.6?

Comment: @OneCricketeer For Java just followed `BUILDING.txt` ,but actually tried Java 12 but also get the same error.As for why not 3.3.6 is we want the main patch of release 3.x but do not want to upgrade from 2.x too ahead because we have some custom code.Current I compile success on server with Centos 7,maybe configure it out is any reference incompatiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

cherry-pick this [commit](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/pull/2886/commits)
or just use the follow version:3.3.1, 3.4.0, 3.2.3, 2.10.3

## Reason

So sorry for missed [this fixed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-17569) !

The most reason is the version of gcc to high(>4.8.5 for me).

But I got the same error after downgrade just because gcc link to gcc-4.8 but `stdio.h` always use system library(make it clear,use `/usr/include/stdio.h`) and it already removed `sys_errlist` and `sys_nerr` !

For more infomation,below is the old version which included in `<stdio.h>`.

```
849 /* Provide the declarations for `sys_errlist' and `sys_nerr' if they
850    are available on this system.  Even if available, these variables
851    should not be used directly.  The `strerror' function provides
852    all the necessary functionality.  */
853 #include <bits/sys_errlist.h>
```

## Conclusion

Missed [this fixed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-17569) for two reasons:

- google it by keyword `sys_nerr +hadoop` and the top 3 are mail archive and hardly to read so skip it too quickly.
- lack knowleage of c
  Realize this is a problem of gcc version at first,but fixed it with a wrong way just because most answer just suggest `apt install gcc-<some version>` and `update-alternative add` but no tips for standard library link.
  Continue to focus on gcc just bucause exclude all the part I am so sure about it but only gcc left because I really not good at it.